# Trying to add a edit text and image button to Action Bar with OnClick Method

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-actionbar

So I am trying to do a action bar similar to Facebook's app and many others. The action bar has a function where you can type in the edit text and then press the save button. However my attempt has failed so far. The layout is is the menu.xml using app:actionLayout which refers to my layout for the item. But the app crashes when I put it under OnCreate and it also does not function when called under OnCreateOptionsMenu. Anybody can help with this?

Here is the Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:weightSum="1">

  <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="57dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:id="@+id/postButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_send_now"
    />

  <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editMessage"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/postButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/postButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/postButton"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="@string/search_title"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_message"
      app:actionLayout="@layout/message_fragment"
      app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_chat"
      android:title="@string/message_item"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

And here is my code in the Activity:

```
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater ().inflate (R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    View view = menu.findItem(R.id.action_message).getActionView();

    view.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    final EditText editMessage = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editMessage);


    final ImageButton actionSendButton = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.postButton);


    actionSendButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Post post = getCurrentPost ();

            post.setPost (editMessage.getText ().toString ());

            post.setGamer (ParseUser.getCurrentUser ());

            post.saveInBackground (new SaveCallback () {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        setResult (Activity.RESULT_OK);
                        finish ();
                    } else {

                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Posting and Thank You!";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast.makeText (context, text, duration).show ();
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how it is down. I was trying to put it in the action bar but you can do it by adding a fragment and then forcing it to the bottom of the screen.